# Duda insertar proyecto java a proyecto web java

Tags: java

Tengo una proyecto `Java` en mi `workspace` con varias clases que se llama "funciones". Luego creé un proyecto web java añadí el proyecto en `Java build path -> projects`.

Pero una vez que inició en `index` y usado alguna clase del proyecto "funciones" me salta una `Exception` y me he dado cuenta que es por que no está en `web-inf/lib`, porque metiendo a mano un `jar` de ese proyecto no salta.

¿Sabeís como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: No se entiende mucho la pregunta, pero es que agregaste a tu proyecto web una libreria que creaste ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporta tu proyecto a un jar de la siguiente manera 
https://www.albany.edu/faculty/jmower/geog/gog692/ImportExportJARFiles.htm
luego en el proyecto que quieras tener acceso aese jar importalo  así :
http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44

En caso de que eso no funcione prueba creando un paquete nuevo en el proyecto y copiando las clases desde el IDE para que se pueda cambiar el nombre de los paquetes de cada clase y no de error.